# Audio files is not running in the android studio , showing error

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-sound

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1lDH.png)
here you can see the error is coming again ang again
Pls help me, i am unable to run the application due to this.
There is a problem with its format ,it is actually not recogonizing the .mp3 or .wav or any time of sound file format

Comment: Learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder raw and paste the audio file manually instead of pasting it from android studio. Also make sure audio file must not contain Capital letters